# web3 instantly firing callback

Tags: javascript, callback, ethereum, web3js

not sure if I should post this on the Ethereum SE but I have a feeling it is more javascript related, so I'll try here:

I have a very simple smart contract that consists of essentially just a `getNum` function and a `setNum` function.  The smart contract can be viewed here: https://pastebin.com/ci6mbPDq

I am trying to construct a simple frontend to call it. Essentially, I follow this [guide](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial)). A working codepen of my frontend (demonstrating the janky functionality) can be found here: https://codepen.io/heh/pen/PeMmKe As you can see in my codepen, I call my `getNum` function like:

```
BasicToken.getNum(0x64319ca297239d8652a0b5f0f12dd6666cb0e05b,

        function(error, result)
        {
            console.log(result.toNumber());
            document.getElementById("target").innerText = result.toNumber();

        }
    );
```

However, I keep getting "0" as the result. On the other hand, my `setNum` function is able to post a result to the Ropsten blockchain. However, I notice that both function calls seem to be firing off their callback instantly.

Could anyone help me figure out why the function calls return instantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback is not being called immediately, the problem is you're not sending an actual address, which should be a string, and you're sending a number:

```
0x64319ca297239d8652a0b5f0f12dd6666cb0e05b == 5.720054584403591e+47
```

And you get `0` because that invalid address you're sending doesn't exist in the mapping:

```
mapping (address=>uint) map23;
```

And if it doesn't exist it will return the default value for `uint` which is zero.

Send a string and it will work:

```
BasicToken.getNum('0x64319ca297239d8652a0b5f0f12dd6666cb0e05b', () => {})
```

Furthermore, if you only want the current user to retrieve their own value, and not let other users retrieve that data (They can, since it's public, but not that easy), you should use `msg.sender` and drop the function parameter.

```
function getNum() public view returns (uint) {
   return map23[msg.sender];
}
```